# How do change the default sort order of different trees for sale.order.line

Tags: xml, odoo

How do change the default sort order of different trees for sale.order.line

for example :
order by name

```xml
<record id="_view_sale_order_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.line.tree1</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Sales Order Lines" >
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="sequence"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

order by sequence

```xml
<record id="_view_sale_order_line_tree2" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.line.tree2</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Sales Order Lines" >
            <field name="order_id"/>
            <field name="sequence"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 10):

On version 8, you can use the attribute **default_order** in XML code.

In your code:

```
<record id="_view_sale_order_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.line.tree1</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Sales Order Lines" default_order="name">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="sequence"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="_view_sale_order_line_tree2" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.line.tree2</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Sales Order Lines" default_order="sequence">
            <field name="order_id"/>
            <field name="sequence"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Now I'm looking for a way to manage this on previous versions.

Comment: Thanks. I need help in version 6.0 .

Comment: I've never worked on version 6.0. I've found a module which solves this problem on version 7.0. It's a small module, may be it works on 6.0 modifying a couple of lines, since 6.0 and 7.0 aren't such different. Take a look to this page: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/order-one2many-lines-29222#answer-75578

Comment: Thanks, I will review.

Comment: @forvas Thanks, it is works in version 9. At the same you can use **DESC order**. Like this: `<tree string="Sales Order Lines" default_order="sequence desc">`

Answer (score 3):

Specially for sorting in ascending or descending order we had attribute.

```
<record id="_view_sale_order_line_tree2" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">sale.order.line.tree2</field>
<field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
<field name="type">tree</field>
<field name="priority" eval="2"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Sales Order Lines"  default_order="sequence desc">
        <field name="order_id"/>
        <field name="sequence"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Here attribute default_order allow to set ordering of record.

default_order="sequence desc"

and

default_order="sequence asc"

This feature available from version 5.0 to till date of odoo 12.0 version.